# How can I populate my data source methods with the property from the other view controller?

Tags: properties, reference, viewcontroller

I created a simple app which is in the first view controller shows the list of FIFA World Cup events (class ViewController: UITableViewController). And then the details of the event in the DetailVC.

I created events property in my DetailVC (I created the same array in the ViewController):

```
var events = [String]()
```

Then in the DetailVC class, I created worldCupYears property, which is an array of WorldCupYear (a struct that I've created)

```
let worldCupYears: [WorldCupYear]
```

One object from this array looks like that:

```
WorldCupYear(year: "2022 ", numberOfTeams: "32 teams participated", homeFlagImage: UIImage.imageWithBorder(from: UIImage(named: "argentina")!), visitorFlagImage: UIImage.imageWithBorder(from: UIImage(named: "france")!), thirdPlaceFlagImage: UIImage.imageWithBorder(from: UIImage(named: "croatia")!), fourthPlaceFlagImage: UIImage.imageWithBorder(from: UIImage(named: "morocco")!), finalDescription: "Argentina - France 3:3 (a.e.t) (5-3 p.)", thirdPlaceDescription: "Croatia - Morocco 2:1", topScorer: "Golden Boot: Kylian Mbappé  8 goals", mvp: "Golden Ball: Lionel Messi ", goldenGlove: "Golden Glove: Emiliano Martínez ", finalLabelText: "Final", thirdPlaceLabelText: "Third place", versus: "-", secondVersus: "-")
```

Then in the viewDidLoad() function of DetailVC I populated my events array, so that it contains only years from those WorldCupYear objects.

```
events = worldCupYears.map { $0.year }
```

Then in my first view controller class (called ViewController), I created a property which is a reference of the DetailVC (the second VC):

```
var detailVC: DetailVC?
```

I want to populate my numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt methods with the detailVC?.events.

I could just create an events array in the ViewController like that:

```
    var events = ["1930 ", "1934 ", "1938 ", "1942 & 1946", "1950 ", "1954 ", "1958 ", "1962 ", "1966 ", "1970 ", "1974 ", "1978 ", "1982 ", "1986 ", "1990 ", "1994 ", "1998 ", "2002  & ", "2006 ", "2010 ", "2014 ", "2018 ", "2022 ", "2026  &  & "]
```

But I would want to do it in a more esthetic way.

I also know that I need to initialize somehow this detailVC property.

I've tried to do it in the viewDidLoad() function of my ViewController class, and then assign the results to the class property called events (array of Strings) like that:

```
        detailVC = DetailVC()
        events = detailVC?.events ?? []
```

I want to populate my numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt methods with the detailVC?.events. I want it to give me the array of years.